# Sharing an excel workbook with a colleuage without using the web version of excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, file-sharing

I'm working with a colleague on an a shared excel workbook. We're on the same network so I followed the instructions by saving it to my OneDrive going to share, adding his email and it sent him a link to the file.

When he uses that link, it'll open excel in a browser version and we can make changes simultaneously but we're finding the browser version to be cumbersome. I've tried to email that file and I can't see any changes he makes in the file like I can when he's making changes in the web version.

Is there a way for him to be working on the same file within Excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but your colleague would need a OneDrive account as well. If you share the file to the email address associated with their OneDrive account, the file should appear in the 'shared' section of their OneDrive web interface.

Select the file, and your colleague should be able to open the file in the office application with collaboration enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the workbook defaults to opening in the browser, you can switch to the desktop app by clicking the 'Editing' button and selecting 'Open in Desktop App'

[image]

Further, if you and your colleague want to always open in the Desktop App by default, then go to File>Options>Advanced>Link Handling and check the box next to 'Open supported hyperlinks to Office files in Office desktop apps':

[image]

More details [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-file-links-directly-in-office-desktop-apps-fe241745-9e05-4142-9ba8-1bb1dc044773).